# How to quit key sequence using evil / spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

I'm using spacemacs in evil mode and I'd like to remap my escape key to the right arrow key (It's easily accessible for me due to a global remapping which is useful in another application). I had most success so far with either of these commands:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<right>") (kbd "<escape>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<right>") 'evil-escape)
```

However, there is one thing I didn't manage to get right yet. When I press, for example 'd', it expects another key (like another 'd' to delete the whole line), but pressing  won't abort that key sequence. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "<right>") 'evil-normal-state)`

The documentation for evil-scape is here: http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#escaping

Comment: I just did, it didn't work. But if I understand it correctly, it expects a key sequence, not a single key. How would I do that? I already tried ["<right>"] and (kbd "<right>") without success.

Comment: Try binding it directly as stated here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/evil-escape/blob/master/README.md#assign-a-key-binding-directly

Comment: you might also bypass evil-escape entirely and bind it this way: `(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<right>") 'evil-normal-state)`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither worked.

Comment: So `(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<right>") 'evil-normal-state)` works for me. You might have to disable evil-escape first though. If it doesn't work for you then there is likely something else in your config that is inhibiting it.

Comment: I just tried it with a clean .spacemacs file and added just the line you mentioned. If I press 'd' and then '<right>', the character under the cursor still gets deleted, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: So I'm no longer sure that I fully understand what you want (if so, sorry for that!). I thought what you wanted was a reliable way to use `<right>` to go to normal mode. But if it is just to cancel a key sequence why not use `C-g`? That seems to work as a universal cancellation sequence. Given that `d` in normal mode expects a further modifier, of which `<right>` is one, I don't think you can get what you want without doing some significant key remapping.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My intention is, that `<right>` behaves like pressing `ESC` (or `C-g`). I had no problem getting most of this to work, but I can't get `<right>` to abort a key sequence (as stated in the title). So you think there is no way of making `<right>` behave like `ESC` or `C-g`?

Comment: Actually, now that I understand what you want (I was being a bit dense before!) I think you could probably get what you want using `(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "<right>") 'evil-normal-state)`. This works for me in the case of motions like using `d` in normal to delete something and then `<right>` to cancel and go back to the normal state.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I searched for! Works like a charm!

Comment: great - I updated my original answer.